# Android large canvas with multiple translated coordinates scroll to particular drawing without touch

Tags: android, canvas, coordinates, draw, translate

Using a custom view in android with larger width and height of 1000x1000 and wrapped in Horizontal scrollview. And to draw a path using **canvas.drawPath(path, paint)**

Code snippet

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/childLinear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CustomCanvas
                android:id="@+id/canvas"
                android:layout_width="1000dp"
                android:layout_height="1000dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Before start drawing the path, using **canvas.translate(width / 2f, height / 2f)** to shift the origin to center of canvas.

Have a small horizontalscroll viewport for scrolling, and

> need to scroll the drawPath line always to be centered in the
> scrollview viewport.

After translate the coordinates, the starting x,y is shifted to center and multiple translation will do based on condition.

How to calculate the original x,y position of the line and scroll to that drawing?

Thanks, helps appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out myself, just stored the difference between view x,y and canvas translated x,y like below.

```
var offsetX = width/2f
var offsetY = height/2f
translate(width/2f,height/2f)
offsetX+= 100
offsetY+= 100
translate(100,100)
```

End of the all the canvas operations, offsetX, offsetY will have the last drawn coordinates in the view.